# MySQL walrus operator on local variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery, window-functions

So I have a procedure that looks like this

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE slct()
        BEGIN
        DECLARE ttl INT DEFAULT 0;
        SELECT NULL AS price, NULL AS account_id, NULL as max_amount, NULL as total
        FROM sellers
        UNION ALL
        SELECT price, account_id, max_amount,  ttl := ttl + max_amount
        FROM (SELECT * FROM sellers ORDER BY price ASC) C where selling_currency_id = :buying and buying_currency_id = :buying_with and ttl < :quantity
        END
```

It gives me a syntax error because of the walrus operator here : `ttl := ttl + max_amount`. If this was a user variable (`@ttl`), that walrus operator would work, but the fact that @ttl is not scoped would introduce a few bugs in my queries.

So I was wondering : how would I make that `:=` work / replace it with something equivalent ?

EDIT :

I found out about the INTO keyword and now my query looks like this. Still says that I have a syntax error though...

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE select_buy(
            IN buying BIGINT UNSIGNED,
            IN buying_with BIGINT UNSIGNED,
            IN quantity BIGINT UNSIGNED,
            INOUT ttl BIGINT UNSIGNED
        )
        BEGIN
        SELECT NULL AS price, NULL AS account_id, NULL as max_amount, NULL as total
        FROM sellers
        UNION ALL
        SELECT price, account_id, max_amount,  (SELECT (ttl + max_amount) INTO ttl) AS total
        FROM (SELECT * FROM sellers ORDER BY price ASC) C where selling_currency_id = buying and buying_currency_id = buying_with and ttl < quantity
        END
```

Comment: Only user-defined variables may be used as assignement operator destination, not local variables. *the fact that @ttl is not scoped would introduce a few bugs in my queries.* ?? How this can be? provide a modelling fiddle please.

Comment: What are `:buying`, `:buying_with`, and `:quantity`? Those look like PDO placeholders, but I don't think you can use them in a procedure.

Comment: I suppose because of concurency ? I don't think there is any lock on @total ? or am I totally wrong ? (yes those are placeholders)

Comment: They're session variables, and each connection has its own variables.

Comment: You don't have to worry about your `@total` interfering with someone else's.

Answer (score 0):

My code wasn't working with @total because I wasn't resetting @total (even though it looks like it). I added `SET @total = 0` and now everything works.